# Projective linear variety can be defined by a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, projective-space

Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space, $\mathbb{P}(V)$ the projective space derived from $V$, $\pi:V-\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}(V)$ the canonical surjection and $(e_i)_{0\leq i\leq n}$ a basis of $V$.

Suppose $W$ is a linear subspace of $V$ of dimension $r+1$. Then it is asserted that $\pi(W-0)\cong\mathbb{P}(W)$ can be defined by

> a system of $n-r$ homogeneous linear equations
> $$\sum_{i=0}^n\xi_i\alpha_{ij}=0,\,(1\leq j\leq n-r)$$ between
> homogeneous coordinates $(\xi_i)_{0\leq i\leq n}$ of a point of
> $\mathbb{P}(V)$ w.r.t. the basis $(e_i)_{0\leq i\leq n}$, the left
> hand sides being linearly independent forms on $V$.

I can't understand this at all; what is being asserted here?–Let me state what I know. Let $(x^*_j)_{1\leq j\leq n-r}$ be a basis of the orthogonal $W'$ of $W$ in $V^*$. Then
$$W=\{x\in V\ |\langle x,x^*_j\rangle=0\text{ for all }1\leq j\leq n\}.$$ That is to say, $W$ is defined by the system of equations
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\alpha_i\langle e_i,x^*_j\rangle=0,\,(1\leq j\leq n-r).$$
Apart from this, what else is the quoted result stating? What does it mean to say that $\pi(W-0)$ is defined by such a system of linear equations?

Comment: What inner product have you defined on $V$?

Comment: By the orthogonal $W'$ you mean the annihilator of $W$. I would probably write the pairing of $V^*$ with $V$ in the other order, i.e., $\langle x^*_j,x\rangle$ or $x_j^*(x)$. @paulblartmathcop — no inner product.